# Qt5 installer does not find debugger

Tags: qt, gdb

I installed Qt5.15.2 with the online community-version installer on Ubuntu 20.04. In QtCreator I find the compilers but not the debugger. On my system I also have `GDB`:

```
$apt policy gdb
gdb:
  Installed: 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04
  Candidate: 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04
  Version table:
 *** 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

But usually the Qt installer should prepare the debugger as well. In many years I never had to configure it manually.

I tried to manually add the system debugger (`/usr/bin/gdb`) but QtCreator says it's unknown:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify that the executable at `/usr/bin/gdb` exists?  You can type `which gdb` in a terminal and it reports this path?

Comment: @Ray, yes: `$ which gdb` `/usr/bin/gdb`

Comment: Does [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/116031/debugging-in-qt-creator-5-15-0-doesn-t-work/14) help?  (See the very last reply on this page.)  I'm using the qtcreator that goes with Ubuntu 20.10 and it is fine.  But it is older than what you're using:  Qt Creator 4.13.2 using Qt 5.14.2 .  Perhaps you can consider trying the version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04?  At least see if it works and then you can rule out whether the problem is your version of qtcreator or gdb?

Comment: Thanks. Before, I want to understand this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637505/gdb-prints-nothing-when-called

Comment: To fix it I had to remove `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I guess `/usr/bin/python` is left over from an earlier version of Ubuntu.  If you have `aptitude`, you can type `aptitude show python-is-python3` and install this package.  But why `/usr/bin/python` was causing that, I do not know.  Probably `gdb` relies on `python` and it was going to `/usr/bin/python` first.  Without it, maybe it then goes to `python3`.  All a guess, of course.  I looked at [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gdb) and `gdb` does rely on `python`...

Comment: Anyway, good to hear you solved your problem!